# Given n points $z\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $|z| = 1 $, find a polynomial that the maximal values of the polynomial at those points is minimum.

Tags: polynomials, optimization

Given $n$ points $z\in\mathcal{C}$ such that $|z| = 1 $, find a polynomial with degree less than $n$ such that the maximal values of the polynomial at those points is minimum and $p(0) =1$.

I am thinking about orthogonal polynomials but it looks like I need to do complex integrals. Also thinking about optimization, Lagrange multipliers perhaps, not sure how to begin.